# Configuring Glassfish 3.0 for profiling with NetBeans on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

This is related to a [known bug in NetBeans 7.](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=205349) NetBeans has a wizard to configure Glassfish for profiling, but the configuration gets garbled when there's a space in the path where NetBeans is installed (which is the case in the default installation, so I have no idea how they didn't catch that one).

I'd like to figure out how to work around this. (I could rename the NetBeans app, but that would cause other problems, so let's forget that for now.) NetBeans is putting this into my domain.xml, which is plainly wrong:

```
<profiler enabled="true" name="NetBeansProfiler">
   <jvm-options>-agentpath:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans</jvm-options>
   <jvm-options>7.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk15/mac/libprofilerinterface.jnilib=/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans</jvm-options>
   <jvm-options>7.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/profiler/lib,5140</jvm-options>
</profiler>
```

(`/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.0.app` is where I have NetBeans installed)

What I'd like to know is, what are the *correct* JVM options? That way, I could put them in the file manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. (Line breaks added for readability, inside `<jvm-options>` it's actually all one line.) Note the double quotes - these are needed if the path contains spaces.

```xml
<profiler enabled="true" name="NetBeansProfiler">
          <jvm-options>"-agentpath:/Applications/NetBeans
             /NetBeans 7.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans
             /profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/mac/libprofilerinterface.jnilib=
             /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.0.app/Contents
             /Resources/NetBeans/profiler/lib,5140"</jvm-options>
</profiler>
```

The format goes like this:

```
-agentpath:$LIB_FILE=$LIB_DIR,$PORT
```

This works with Glassfish 3.0.1. There was a [bug in some earlier versions](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-4434) where it would choke on quotes inside `jvm-options`, so adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinstalling netbeans, try creating a symlink to it that does not contain a space and edit the config file to use the symlinked path.

Comment: This doesn't help at all. The problem here is that I don't know the correct incantation to put in the config file.

Comment: That's what I get trying to answer something before I've had my morning coffee. Glad you found it.